# Remove notification observer in superclass or subclass in ios

Tags: ios5, nsnotificationcenter

I have registered for a notification in the superclass. The observer is handled in the subclass which calls the super implementation. Do I remove the observer in the dealloc of the superclass or subclass ?

Answer (score 2):

You should be removing the observer from the same class you registered for the notification.

Comment: I tried unregistering in the superclass. But I sometimes get crashes due to the view controller being nil in the notification handler.

Comment: And did you find out why the view controller was nil?

Comment: It happened on another users device. The crash report said [UIImageView navigationItem] - unable to respond to selector. That code was in the notification handler. That line was actually [self navigationItem]. So I think that view controller got deallocated at some point during the notification handler. But I am not sure what caused it.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small class that will automatically remove registered notifications. You can find it at [AutoRemoveObserver](https://github.com/intuit/AutoRemoveObserver)